# What to do with boundary terms in Fourier transformation of a derivative?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

I have the system:
\begin{align}
\tag{1} y_t&=ay_{xx}+by_x, \ \ \ x\in\mathbb{R},t>0,\\
\tag{2}y(x,0)&=f(x) , \qquad \ \ \ \ \ \ x\in\mathbb{R}
\end{align}
where $y$ is bounded and $$\lim_{|x|\rightarrow +\infty}y_x=0.$$ Also $f$ is sufficiently smooth, and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

I want to transform (1) and (2) using the Fourier transformation.
$$\hat y(λ,t)=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}y(x,t) e^{iλx}dx$$

\begin{align}
\tag{3} \hat{y}_{xx}(λ,t)&=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}y(x,t)_{xx} e^{iλx}dx=\dots \\
&=-λi\cdot \lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}y(a,t)e^{iλa}+λi \lim_{a\rightarrow -\infty }y(a,t)e^{iλa}+λ^2 i^2 \hat y(λ,t)\end{align}

and
\begin{align}
\tag{4} \hat y_x(λ,t) &=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}y_x(x,t) e^{iλx}dx=\dots \\
&= \lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}y(a,t)e^{iλa}- \lim_{a\rightarrow -\infty }y(a,t)e^{iλa}-λ i \hat y(λ,t)
\end{align}

and
$$\tag{5} \hat y_t(λ,t)=\frac{d}{dt} \left (\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}y e^{iλx}dx \right )$$

$$(1),(3),(4),(5) \Rightarrow \hat {y}_t +(aλ^2 +iλ)\hat u(λ,t)=(b-aλi)\left [\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}y(a,t)e^{iλa}-\lim_{a\rightarrow -\infty}y(a,t)e^{iλa} \right]$$

That is the transformation I find, is it correct?

How can I eliminate the limits? Can I substitute them with a number? If $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}y(x,t)=0$$ then I eliminate them. But I don't know that.

Comment: @littleO, haha he totally drew me in with the previous title. I suggested a new one anyway though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need $\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm\infty}y(x,t)=0$ for the Fourier transform to exist, so you have assumed this implicitly in defining $\hat{y}(\lambda,t)$. It then follows that the boundary terms coming from integration by parts when calculating $\hat{y}_x(\lambda,t)$ and $\hat{y}_{xx}(\lambda,t)$ will be zero.

Comment: Joe@you mean that is always lim y(x,t)=o ?Because if y(x,t) is bounded then  the integral is not infinite but a real number.But i don' t  really understand why lim y(x,t)=0 when |x| goes to infinity.Could you expain more this to me please?why the fourier transformation does not exist if this limit exists byt it is not 0?

Comment: @george_ioanidis the limits to infinity in the integral $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}y(x,t) e^{iλx}dx$ only exist when $\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm\infty}y(x,t)=0$. Try sketching a function with $\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm\infty}y(x,t)=1$, and then think about the area underneath it. Can you find such a function which has a finite area underneath?

Comment: @Joethanks i get it ,the integral would be infinite then,byt why it gives than u(x,t) is bounded?from the limit that is 0 it is obvius that u(x,t) is bounded.

Comment: For the Fourier transform of $y$ to exist, it is necessary that $y$ be bounded in all of $\mathbb{R}$. The limit only tells you about behaviour at infinity.

Comment: @george_ioanidis, I forgot to tag you in my list comment